# Debezium data type conversion issue in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, debezium, debezium-engine

I have configured a spring boot application to `capture changed` data from a Postgres database using `debezium` java library. This Postgres database already has `orafce extension` enabled. Since this extension is enabled there exists a new data type named **date** (provided from orafce extension ) in addition to the original Postgres **date** data type.

When a changed record is captured by the spring boot application, if that record contains a column with data type **date** (Postgres date data type), debezium tries to resolve that type with the other **date** ( data type newly added from orafce extension)

Therefore it throws an exception always. Could you please let me know whether there is a solution for this problem

Thank you